# Excel 2013 conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have data in multiple cells in a row. I want to highlight cells A to K based on cell L value (text from a list). Further to this if I place any text to cells M or N or P then all the highlights must be removed. This means if I have any text (any name) in cells M, N, P then no formatting required.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a formula for the conditional format and combine the two conditions:

- column L in the same row is equal to your trigger text, for example "yes"
- the combined cells of M, N and O in the same row must have a text length of 0

That can be expressed with the formula

=AND($L2="yes",LEN($M2&$N2&$O2)=0)

See screenshot for an example. The conditional formatting starts in row 2, hence the references to L2, M2, etc.

[image]

Comment: As an addition, the conditional formatting rule needs to use "**Applies to**" range of "`=$A:$K`".  Also, I think the OP is trying to match values in L to some list of text.  Therefore, I would modify the formula to something like "`=AND(COUNTIF(SOME_RANGE,$L1)>0,LEN($M1&$N1&$P1)=0)`".  Where "SOME_RANGE" points to the list of text to match, e.g. $Q$1:$Q$5, if you have 5 strings in Q1 to Q5 that need to be matched against the values in column L.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked the way I needed it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Please accept my post as the answer as explained in the [Tour]